# how can I retrieve the data in the session in express app correctly when both client and server have the same origin?

Tags: express, session, cors, session-cookies, express-session

I after login I set the data in the session: I checked that it is in there. However, when I do another request from the frontend the session does not have the data I set previously.
I added cockieParser but the req.session still does not contain the data I set.

Both the server and the client are working in the localhost.
I tried to disable the cors middleware in the express but then the requests from client are blocked.

Here is the backend code:

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret: "secret",
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 hour in milliseconds 
  },
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));

in the login route:
...
 if (token) {req.session.token = token;}
...
```

The client code:

```
 fetch(`${API_URL}/facilities/all`, {
        method: "GET", 
        // credentials: "include",         
      })
```

If I add the credentials it returns an error because the error says that credential can be sent due to access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*" , I think it comes from the cors() middleware in the backend.
When I remove remove the cors middleware and send credentials I am not allowed because of the same origin.

How can I fix this code? How can I set and get the token from req.session correctly?

Comment: If client and server have the same origin, you don't need CORS. Please describe which errors you observe for requests from the client. "Requests are blocked" is too generic.